# How can i manipulate data for React & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a beginner at React & Redux, if you give me any tips, I would be very grateful.

My data is like this:

```
{
  createdAt:"2018-07-06T15:59:10.493+03:00"
  enabledDomains:[]
  enabledOnMobile:true
  enabledUrls:[]
  fontColor:"#38998F"
  fullPageOnMobile:false
  id:"bf48b146-c13e-4269-bb9f-4c68ced1ccda"
  margin:12
}
```

When I want to update the `margin`, `fullPageOnMobile` or `fontColor` everything is good. On the other hand, when I try for `enabledDomains` or `enabledUrls` arrays, my action data is changing except `enabledDomains` or `enabledUrls`. I changed it in state and sent true data with action. But it did not change.

My reducer is like this:

```
case UPDATE_WEB_WIDGETS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: action.data,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
  };
```

Comment: If you log `action.data`, what results do you get for those 2 arrays?

Comment: need more info? your reducer and action files would help

Comment: `createdAt:"2018-07-06T15:59:10.493+03:00"
enabledDomains:Array(2)
0:{name: "a"}
1:{name: "b"}`, this is my state data .                                                       
                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                               `createdAt:"2018-07-06T15:59:10.493+03:00"
enabledDomains:[] `, this is my `action.data` when put log .

Comment: There's really not much to go on, there's nothing wrong with that you're seemingly doing. Can you reproduce this on https://codesandbox.io/, maybe?

Comment: `export const updateWebWidgetsAction = (token, payload) => ({
  type: UPDATE_WEB_WIDGETS,
  token,
  payload,
});` this is my action .                                                                                            
 And my reducer is ; on the top which is start with `UPDATE_WEB_WIDGETS_SUCCESS `

Comment: Is this the reducer which is responsible for updating the data you provided in your question? I can't see the relation here. Do you want to update `enabledDomains` with a payload? Then, please update your question and provide all the related action creators and reducers.

Comment: Ah, I see now. `data` in the state, not the state itself. Ok. But in the reducer, you are updating it directly with your data. So, it overriding the old `data` totally. If you provide the exact shape of your `action.data` we can help a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to simply return your updated data array to the Redux store. This is because Redux will evaluate the arrays to be equal and therefore will not update.

Try something like this

```
case UPDATE_WEB_WIDGETS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: [...state.data, action.data]
    loading: false,
    error: false,
  };
```